# Delete rows that violate constraint after update postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table in my postgres database that is basically a dictionary of universities with two columns: id and name.

I need to do a little cleanup of the dictionary and I need to perform operations as such:

```
update university_dictionary set name=replace(name, 'NY', 'New York');
```

The thing is that there is a unique constraint set on the `name` column so if there is a `University of NY` and `University of New York` then this update will cause a unique constraint violation. Is there a way of deleting the record that violates the constraint after the update?

Comment: I'm confused why you would want to wait until *after* the update to delete the record.  Why not just delete the extra records?

Comment: Good point, although I'm not sure what the `where` condition for the delete statement would be in this case?

Comment: @Matt: Which of the 2 rows do you want remaining in the end? You need to have a way to choose between those 2, and that's your `WHERE` clause. Deleting after the update (if it was possible) would be random/impossible anyway if you can't tell those two apart anymore.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which one remains, just for the sake of it always the original could remain. Are you saying that for each one of the cases like University of NY I need to write a different specific statement that will delete this entry?

Comment: @Matt : if keeping the original one is what you want then this probably should only be a `DELETE` I believe. If you want to delete rows that would create a conflict then `DELETE FROM university_dictionary WHERE EXIST (...) ` might be what you want (hard to say since we've strayed from the original question a bit).

Comment: If the UPDATE threw an error, then nothing was changed in the table. So "after" the update there is no row that violates the the constraint (because that's precisely the job of the constraint to prevent that situation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with two queries.

```
delete from university_dictionary a
where name like '%NY%' and 
    exists(select 1 from university_dictionary b
                where replace(a.name, 'NY', 'New York')=b.name);

update university_dictionary set name=replace(name, 'NY', 'New York')
where name like '%NY%';
```

Test this a bit before executing on life data.  Don't have much data to try it on :-)

Best regards,
Bjarni